# postgres: How to give read privileges to a user?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have imported a .sql file into postgres. I created a database named "yaq" and imported it into the database.

```
psql=# grant all privileges on database yaq to Jannat;
postgres@server:~$ psql yaq
psql (9.1.8, server 9.1.9)
Type "help" for help.

yaq=# \dt
              List of relations
 Schema |      Name       | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-----------------+-------+----------
 public | relationalfacts | table | yaq
 public | spatial_ref_sys | table | postgres
(2 rows)

yaq=# select * from relationalfacts
yaq-# ;
 id | relation | arg1 | arg2 | timebegin | timeend | location | locationlatitude | locationlongitude | primarywitness | context 
----+----------+------+------+-----------+---------+----------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+---------
(0 rows)
```

I think since I have grant all privileges to owner "yaq" and not "yago" therefore I am not able to read the relation. Is there some way by which I may give read privileges for the relational table yaq to the user Jannat? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GRANT ALL ON DATABASE ...` does *not* recursively grant rights to the schemas, functions, tables, etc within that database.

`GRANT ALL` for a `DATABASE` grants the `USAGE` and `CONNECT` rights for the database. That is all.

To grant rights on a table, use one of the table grant statements or `GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ... TO ...`.

See [the PostgreSQL manual on `GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) for details.

Before `GRANT`ing to users, consider if you should be using a few roles instead, and then `GRANT`ing the users rights to act as those roles. Defining roles (groups) at the beginning will save you lots of hassle later if you start adding more users.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. How do I check what is the the name of the schema of my table? I am checking the relations contained in the table with the help of \dt

Comment: @JannatArora If you don't know the schema then they're in `public`, the default schema. See `\dn` to list schemas. `\dt` lists the schema as the first column in the output.